# react component navbar not working in live server

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm new to react and I'm trying to implement a Navbar or any other component using React-bootstrap 5 . when I do npm start nothing is being displayed on the live server.
SCREENSHOTS ARE ATTACHED IN LINK

AS SOON AS I AM IMPORTING SOMETHING LIVE SERVER IS DISPLAYING NOTHING AND THE ERROR IS GENERATING

Compiled with warnings.

src/App.js
Line 1:8:  'react' is defined but never used no-unused-vars. DELETED EVERYTHING AND STARTED FROM SCRATCH 3 TIME.

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure to import the component navbar into your app component if you intend to modulize the project. Then i'd try to change the "const navbar = () => { " into "function Navbar{" and try to add ; after return )

Comment: import './App.css';
import navbar from "./components/navbar";


function App() {
  return (
 <navbar/>
  );
}

export default App;
 added this already

Comment: trying to correct it since 6 hrs no success

Comment: can you share a screenshot or something?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDP4U.png 
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc6aM.png 
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW2wA.png

Comment: Components must be with the first letter Upper case. Try to change them into Home, About, Navbar etc. also try to check if the paths to the components inside App are correct